# Differentiate model,views and controller in MVC of visual studio 2010

Tags: model-view-controller

I read MVC concept, but i dont understand which type of code should be in controll and which one in model.

Comment: Are this mvc same as like BAO,DAO in VS2008?

Answer (score 0):

I thing you can understand what is a view. view is responsible of the display or UI.

Model is the part where you define the classes which you want to work as entities in your application.

Controller is the class which you write your program logic. therefore a controller will provide data to the views using Models, retrieve data from views using Model and perform any task that you program wants.

for example if the program is for a library system you can have a Model class for Book which could look like the following

```
public class BookViewModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Publisher {get;set;}
        public string ISBN {get;set;}
    }
```

the controller class has the operations like View details about the book, Create new book, etc.. the following is an example

```
public class BooksController : Controller
    {
       //
        // GET: /Books/Details/5
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
           // your logic goes here.
            return View(bookViewModel);
        }

      [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create( BookViewModel bookViewModel)
        {
            // your logic goes here
        }
    }
```

I think this will help you a little to understand the concept

Cheers.

Jayanga.

Comment: so all the logic except storing the data should in controller right?

Comment: you used [HttpGet] and [HttpPost] ,what is this and why you place above the function

Comment: I posted a code for Asp.Net MVC 3. In that you can define Get and Post operations. [HttpPost] means you are accepting a Post request from the View.

Comment: And yes, all the logic is placed in the controller